# Simple way to copy files

Tags: ocaml

Is there a simple way to copy files using the standard OCaml library, or a widely-used lightweight library (preferably one that is actively maintained on opam)?

In module `Sys`, there are functions `file_exists`, `remove` and `rename`, but nothing to copy the contents of a file to a new file.

In module `Unix`, there are `mkdir`, `unlink`, `rename` and `link`. This last one creates a hard link, which is close, but not really a copy.

Note that something like `Sys.command("cp source dest")` is not a good solution, since it is not portable and brings other issues.

Comment: It's fairly easy to implement a copy function. The OCaml Unix book has a working example: https://ocaml.github.io/ocamlunix/files.html#sec33

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ocaml-fileutils](https://www.le-gall.net/sylvain+violaine/ocaml-fileutils.html)  is a library to provide pure OCaml functions to manipulate real file and filename.

Comment: It looks like https://github.com/gildor478/ocaml-fileutils/ contains newer development (your link announces v0.4.0, while 0.5.3 is available)